# Unable to use apt-get after attempting to install kubuntu-desktop in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: apt, package-management, kde, 15.10

I was trying to install kde in my ubuntu 15.10.

I used the following command

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

I encountered these two errors--

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kde-telepathy-minimal :
                Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>= 15.04.0)
                         but it is not going to be installed.
```

Now whenever I try to use `apt-get` it shows this error continuously.

I am unable to even remove the half installed `kubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: tried installing `kde-config-telepathy-accounts`?

Comment: What's the output of `apt-get install --dry-run kde-config-telepathy-accounts`?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error. Attempting to install kde-config-telepathy-accounts just gave another error message.

`sudo apt-get autoremove -f kde-telepathy*` fixed the problem by forcibly removing the offending packages and giving me control of apt again.